# Visual Studio 2015 freezes when i start debugging in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, freeze

i have a big problem. I open visual studio 2015 Community Edition and everything works fine up to the point when I start debugging a code in C++(I press ctrl + f5). Then it freezes and i can't do anything but close it form task manager.I also noticed that when i open older projects and write new code everything works fine , but when i open a new project it freezes when i try to debug it. Here is the error description:
    Description:
    A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: AppHangB1
Application Name:   devenv.exe
Application Version:    14.0.23107.0
Application Timestamp:  559b7ead
Hang Signature: a3e2
Hang Type:  6144
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1026
Additional Hang Signature 1:    a3e25b996bfe70578783a093f3f99999
Additional Hang Signature 2:    b946
Additional Hang Signature 3:    b94652f300fc30cb7bed34d10dd50dbf
Additional Hang Signature 4:    a3e2
Additional Hang Signature 5:    a3e25b996bfe70578783a093f3f99999
Additional Hang Signature 6:    b946
Additional Hang Signature 7:    b94652f300fc30cb7bed34d10dd50dbf
```

I saw some fixes but i have no idea where to put this 
    "Devenv /ResetSettings SettingsFile" (in cmd it does not work and i have no idea where to type it). PLEASE HELP !!!!

Comment: Can you get a simple "Hello World!" program to work?  Or does it have something to do with your specific project's code?

Comment: I cant get a simple "Hello World!" program to work. It doesn't matter what kind of code i type it always freezes !

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your solution/project or the installation.  Can you run it with just F5?

Comment: No,it freezes again ! I also noticed that the new projects that i create are not shown in the recent projects tab , just the old ones are shown , in which i can type and everything works properly !

Comment: Sorry. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: `devenv /ResetSettings SettingsFile` will need to be run in the visual studio installation directory, otherwise it will say something like "devenv is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file". Did you run it in the correct directory? You also need to specify an actual settings file, not just the string "SettingsFile". See [the msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)

Comment: Make an exclusion for your project directory in your anti-malware product.  If it is Avast or ESET then get rid of it completely.

Comment: ty man you da real mvp :)))

Answer (score 10):

To post it as an answer.

Like Hans Passant said: **Disable your Antivirus**. Avast caused me 3 hours of debugging because of this.

Comment: This Happened to me on visual studio community 19-01-2016

Comment: Ditto here for VS Community 2013.  That Avast is a bloody nuisance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after finding the shield in Avast that was causing the hold up. I found a way to get it to work without turning off Avast.

1. Have a folder to place all your programs in.
2. Go into your Avast settings and Select "Active Protection".
3. Under "File system shield" hit "Customize". (This is where Avast is preventing the .exe)
4. Go to "Exclusions" and add in the path to the folder that's storing all your programs using the browse button.(Remember to hit add after creating the path).

And that's it. After doing this, my programs worked fine as long as they were stored in that folder.